# gem5 compiling problems after adding python2.7 to my ubuntu

Tags: compiling, python-2.7

I had python3.8 originally, and compiled gem5 (X86 and ARM) successfully. then I added python2.7 to run some models. now I got below errors that I have not before when trying to compile gem5 using:

```
scons build/ARM/gem5.opt

scons build/X86/gem5.opt
```

the errors are:

```
Checking for compiler -Wno-self-assign-overloaded support... (cached) yes
AttributeError: Flag Checkpoint already specified:
  File "/home/ahmed/gem5/SConstruct", line 731:
    SConscript('src/SConscript', variant_dir=variant_path, exports=exports)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 660:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 597:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "/home/ahmed/gem5/build/ARM/SConscript", line 466:
    SConscript(os.path.join(root, 'SConscript'), variant_dir=build_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 660:
    return method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 597:
    return _SConscript(self.fs, *files, **subst_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/scons/SCons/Script/SConscript.py", line 286:
    exec(compile(scriptdata, scriptname, 'exec'), call_stack[-1].globals)
  File "/home/ahmed/gem5/build/ARM/sim/OriginalJwan/SConscript", line 114:
    DebugFlag('Checkpoint')
  File "/home/ahmed/gem5/build/ARM/SConscript", line 429:
    DebugFlagCommon(name, (), desc, fmt, tags=tags, add_tags=add_tags)
  File "/home/ahmed/gem5/build/ARM/SConscript", line 400:
    raise AttributeError(f'Flag {name} already specified')
```

Is it because of the extra python version a have added? Are there any possible solutions?

Comment: How did you "add python2.7"? In general, you can install it with `sudo apt install python2`, and run it with the command `python2`. Did you replace python3.8? If so, reinstall Ubuntu, and follow the steps in my comment.

Comment: @guiverc i am using ubuntu20.04 LTS (not ubuntu server)

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi      i added python2.7 (did not replace python 3.8 with 2.7). i added python2.7 by the command (sudo apt install python-is-python2) then (sudo update-alternatives --list python)  then ($ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2 1
$ sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 2 )        Finally  i used ($ sudo update-alternatives --config python) to switch between alternatives.

Comment: You can switch alternatives to make `python` point to python3, and then change your compilation script to work with `python2`

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi python3 is the auto mode (highest priority) , how can i change the compilation script to work the python2?

Comment: Wherever the compilation script calls `python`, change that to `python2`

Comment: I don't know what exactly you are doing, but you can selectively call python2.7 with the command `python2`.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi  can i just keep python3.8 and remove python2.7 from ubuntu safely?

Comment: From Ubuntu 20.04, yes. However, do ensure that no necessary packages are removed when you remove this version of python. Also, if you remove python2.7 then how would you use that for compilation?

Comment: i can try to compile other models to do the same work.... i tried to remove the 2.7 version using   " sudo apt-get remove pyhton2 " .... but it is still there when i try   "pyhton2 --version"

Comment: What is the output of `which python2`?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi  i got " /usr/bin/python2 "

Comment: Are you sure python2 is removed? Maybe ask a new question about how to remove python2

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi i will